# Swift generic array with type constraint

Tags: generics, swift

I'm trying to write a swift method that returns a generic array. I've left out some of the details, but kept the important bit that isn't working for clarity...

```
protocol AProtocol {
    func doSomething()
}

func decode<T: AProtocol>(jsonArray: Array<AnyObject>?) -> [T: AProtocol] {
    //...
    var resultArray = [T: AProtocol]()
    resultArray.append
    //...
}
```

When I specify that the array contains type T: AProtocol, then the append method no longer appears

> [T: AProtocol] does not have a member named append

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line of code:

```
var resultArray = [T: AProtocol]()
```

you are creating a dictionary having key of `T` type and value of `AProtocol` type.

To create an array of `AProtocol`, just use:

```
var resultArray = [AProtocol]()
```

otherwise if you want an array of `T`:

```
var resultArray = [T]()
```

Note that the constraint of `T` implementing the `AProtocol` protocol is set in the function declaration, so you don't have to repeat it again when using `T` in the function body.

Answer (score 1):

This `[T: AProtocol]()` is not array, but dictionary.